# Expansion files, importing downloader library, Studio not liking it

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, helper, apk-expansion-files

I have been trying to work through Android Developers' bogus description on how to implement the Expansion files madness into my perfectly working project and after days spent on it and reading other people's clearer description, it is still not working.

I have managed to import the Licensing Library and the Zip File thing, but when I try to do the same with the Downloader Library, the "Select modules to import" message comes up if I choose the Downloader Library itself, or the "Specify location of the gradle or Android project" message comes up when I try to import the "src" within the Downloader Library.

As the first two (Licensing and Zip) were working perfectly, I thought that my Studio was out of date, so I wiped off the whole thing and reinstalled it without importing any old settings. Bad news, it is still doing the same thing.

What am I doing wrong here?

[Whole downloader library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS2Vq.jpg)
[Src within downloader library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccs6G.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few weeks later I went back to Android Studio from Eclipse to give it another try. They must have done something with it, because it is working just fine.It imports everything as it should.

At this given moment Version23 is the highest one. I have used V.22 for the project, because earlier I had problems with Apache in V.23.

I haven't had any problem with the module versions, but a lot of people have had. Make sure that after importing the modules set up the dependencies and that all the modules are using the same minimum apk and target apk versions as your main project.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get the Downloader library imported as a module into Android Studio 2.1 by editing the project properties file

```
<android_sdk>/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/project.properties
```

change the last line to

> android.library.reference.1=../../market_licensing/library

Then you can import with File > New > New Module.

This will also import the Licensing Library (as 'library' which you can rename), so you do not need to import the Licensing Library first.

Answer (score 1):

even today with the latest android stuio and sdk it did not work to import. what I had to do was removing this last line

```
android.library.reference.1=../market_licensing
```

from downloader_library/project.properties
file and I could import.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the Eclipse project file that is up on the developer site.  If you edit the library directories to point to the actual location of the libraries within the extras folder, all will import correctly.

Comment: Interesting enough, Eclipse was working fine for me. Since then they must have updated Android Studio, because it imports the modules as it should. Thanks anyway.